# SSH Config based on ssh command with port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to convert the following SSH command on a SSH File entry.

My command is as follows:

```bash
ssh -i identity-file.pem -L 20000:internal-host.com:8080 user@remote-host.com -N
```

An this is the current SSH file

```bash
Host remote-host-tunnel
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  HostName remote-host.com
  User user
  PubKeyAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity-file.pem
  ServerAliveInterval 30

Host internal-host-forwarding
  LocalForward 20000 internal-host.com:8080
  Hostname internal-host.com
  ProxyCommand ssh remote-host-tunnel nc %h %p
```

I'm able to reach the tunnel as folows:

```bash
ssh remote-host-tunnel
```

Everything up until this point works fine

But then, when I want to access the internal-host it's not working

```bash
ssh internal-host-forwarding -N
```

The connection does not get established

**Ncat: Connection timed out.**

**kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host**

**Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to to use the ProxyCommand with `netcat` to establish a connection to the internal host, but that is not necessary for port forwarding, just combine the configurations of both hosts into a single entry like this in your ssh config file:

```
Host remote-host-tunnel
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  HostName remote-host.com
  User user
  PubKeyAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity-file.pem
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  LocalForward 20000 internal-host.com:8080
```

Now you can just connect to the `remote-host-tunnel`

```
ssh remote-host-tunnel -N
```

edit: You can also create multiple entries for each internal host like the example below

```
Host remote-host-tunnel
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  HostName remote-host.com
  User user
  PubKeyAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity-file.pem
  ServerAliveInterval 30

Host internal-host-forwarding-1
  Hostname localhost
  Port 20000
  ProxyJump remote-host-tunnel
  LocalForward 20000 internal-host1.com:8080

Host internal-host-forwarding-2
  Hostname localhost
  Port 20001
  ProxyJump remote-host-tunnel
  LocalForward 20001 internal-host2.com:8080
```

and if you want to connect to `internal-host-forwarding-1` do ssh `internal-host-forwarding-1 -N`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was my workaround as well, but I have multiple tunnels that were suppose to connect to different `internal-hosts` that need to go all trough the same `remote-host` . That's why I was trying to keep them separated

Comment: You welcome, I updated my answer